# How can I decrease spaces between equations?

Tags: spacing, equations

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}    
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.5}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Text text text text text text text text text text      
\begin{equation}
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
\end{equation}  
Text text text text text text text text text text  
\begin{equation}
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Spaces between two equations and between equations and text are too big. How can I lower them? I know that using `\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.5}` is responsible for that but I need this command.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I would recommend taking the following measures:

1. Instead of `\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.5}`, load the `setspace` package with the `nodisplayskipstretch` option, and execute the command `setstretch{1.5}` in your document's preamble:

   ```
   ...
   \usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
   \setstretch{1.5}
   ...
   ```

   This way, you won't experience the excessive spacing between lines of text and displayed math material. Also, material in footnotes and in `tabular`-like environments will remain single-spaced.
2. When you have consecutive equations, don't use separate `equation` environments; instead, use the `gather` environment provided by the `amsmath` package. (If the equations should be aligned along, say, their equal signs, use the `align` environment instead of the `gather` environment, and use the `&` (ampersand) character to mark the desired alignment points in each row.) Two consecutive equations could be entered as

   ```
   \begin{gather}
   1 + 2 + 3 = 6 \\
   2 + 4 + 6 = 12
   \end{gather}
   ```

Comment: `\begin{gather} 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 \ 2 + 4 + 6 = 12 \end{gather}` shows two equations in one line.

Comment: Ok, I figured on my own that I need to put ` \\ ` instead of ` \ `

Comment: How can I align to `=` character in equations? When I use `\begin{align} 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 \\ 2 + 4 + 6 = 12 \end{align} ` it aligns to the right.

Comment: You need an & character on each line for an alignment tab.  You can put it anywhere, but I ususally put it in front of the =.

Comment: Just because I'm curious. Why using two consecutive `equation`s is wrong?

Comment: It's not *wrong* to have two consecutive `equation` environments. However, doing so will in general use more space than if you use an environment that "knows" that successive lines are equations rather than switches between text and equations. Moreover, if you use consecutive `equation` environments, you can't align them on, say, the equal sign -- something you could do if you'd use the `align` environment, say.

Comment: +1 for the `gather` environment. I didn't want to mess around with document-wide spacing parameters just because LaTeX didn't "know" I was providing a series of equations.

Comment: But how can I label different equations if I use gather?

Comment: @DávidTóth - You should insert `\label` directives at the end of each line (but before `\\`) in a `gather` environment. You can then `\ref` (or `\eqref`, etc) them just as you would a simple `equation` environment.

Comment: Well, and what if one need to switch from e.g. `align` to `equation` because the alignment tab has changed or must be changed for  space related issues (equation will not fit in one line).
Unfortunately using one line without indentation tab spoils the whole alignment.

Answer (score 40):

TeX uses `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` for the spacing above/below equations. There's also a short version of the former two commands for paragraphs ending/beginning with shorter lines. Here's an example showing the difference:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
Text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{equation}
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
\end{equation}  
Text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{align}
1 + 2 + 3 &= 6 \\
1 + 2 + 3 &= 6
\end{align}

\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}

Text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{equation}
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
\end{equation}  
Text text text text text text text text text text
\begin{align}
1 + 2 + 3 &= 6 \\
1 + 2 + 3 &= 6
\end{align}
\end{document}​
```

The same effect is obtained with/without a modified `\baselinestretch` - it is just clearer when viewed without that set. Of course, you can modify these lengths as needed.

**Edit**: Heed @egreg's suggestion and/or @Mico's answer regarding two equations

Comment: One should never use two consecutive `equation` environment, but rather the `gather` environment provided by **amsmath**

Answer (score 13):

you should use package `setspace` for the vertical spacing. The distance between two equations is set by the short skips!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}    
\usepackage{setspace}\onehalfspacing
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtolength\abovedisplayskip{-0.5\baselineskip}%
  \addtolength\belowdisplayskip{-0.5\baselineskip}%
%  \addtolength\abovedisplayshortskip{-0.5\baselineskip}%
%  \addtolength\belowdisplayshortskip{-0.5\baselineskip}%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Text text text text text text text text text text      
\begin{equation}
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
\end{equation}  
Text text text text text text text text text text  
\begin{equation}
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
1 + 2 + 3 = 6
\end{equation}
some nmore text\par
some more text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case below command fix the problem,

```
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
```

Comment: How does your recommendation differ from what I wrote in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32922/5001)?

Comment: @Mico there is a little difference. You have extra instruction setstretch which I didn’t use.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
\vspace{} or \hspace{}
```

with a negative value to reduce the vertical or horizontal spacing respectively.

Comment: Simple, yet does the work.