# Large space between text and equations when I \begin{equation}

Tags: spacing, equations

When I do this, there is a large space between the text and the equations.  I was wondering if there was a way to solve this. I am using `amsmath`. Thanks a lot

```
\textbf{Solution}

\begin{center}
    \begin{equation*}
        (1+x)(1+y)\geqslant{4}
    \end{equation*}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Too many complications. `{\bf Solution} $$(1+x)(1+y)\geqslant 4$$`.

Comment: @wipet as you know that is the wrong markup for latex, why do you suggest it?

Answer (score 6):

The large space is due to the `center` environment, which adds vertical unneeded space and does nothing useful, since `equation` center its contents by default.

So, simply remove the `center` environment.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\textbf{Solution}

\begin{equation*}
    (1+x)(1+y)\geqslant{4}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

I would also suggest to remove the blank line before the `equation` environment, so to have the following result:

[image]

Comment: but not just that, you shouldn't have a blank line before display math either

Comment: Right @David, I'll add it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

The `equation` environment (including `equation*`) already centres its contents, so there's no need for `center`. Additionally, `center` adds vertical space, as discussed in [When should we use `\begin{center}` instead of `\centering`?][When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23650/5764)) Only use

```
\begin{equation*}
  <stuff>
\end{equation*}
```

If you need to adjust vertical spacing around sparse document elements, then you could consider adjusting certain skips as discussed in [How can I decrease spaces between equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32918/5764) However, that would not be necessary in this case...