# Cannot define spacing between equations

Tags: spacing, equations

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


This example solves a simple equation:   

\begin{equation}
x + 2 = 6 \nonumber
\end{equation}    

\begin{equation}
\Leftrightarrow \nonumber
\end{equation}    

\begin{equation}
x = 4
\end{equation}


It would nice if the spacing between the equations was reduced!

\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

I would like to reduce the spacing before and after the equivalence sign. I tried these [options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32918/how-can-i-decrease-spaces-between-equations) but none of them seems to work. Help!

Comment: never leave a blank line before a display math environment or put one after another,

Comment: cool I did not know that! thanks. can you give that as an answer so I can mark it correct for future reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the `amsmath` package, you should probably be using one of its grouping environment for this.

In this case, you want to display consecutive equations, centered with no special alignement. The `gather` environment does just that:

```
\begin{gather}
x + 2 = 6 \notag\\
\Leftrightarrow \notag\\
x = 4
\end{gather}
```

[image: result]